# MongoDB $match anything

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

On the front end,

```
  <select ng-model="selected.year">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
  </select>
  <select ng-model="selected.year">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
  </select>
  <select ng-model="selected.month">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
      <option value="May">May</option>
  </select>
$scope.params = {year: '2015', month: 'Apr', type: 'A'}
```

It works fine when all the boxes are selected, but I want to make it flexible to not have to select everything, meaning if the user selects only the year and month, it will return all the 'types'.

On the server side, the query looks something like this:

```
Collection.aggregate({ $match: { year: req.body.year, month: req.body.month, type: req.body.type}
}....etc)
```

The problem is it returns nothing if one of the fields is not selected. How do I ask MongoDB to return all for a field that is not selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by building up your `$match` value programmatically to omit the fields without values:

```js
var match = {};
if (req.body.year) {
    match.year = req.body.year;
}
if (req.body.month) {
    match.month = req.body.month;
}
if (req.body.type) {
    match.type = req.body.type;
}
Collection.aggregate({ $match: match}, ...);
```